# Inject secrets from codebuild into an EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Is it possible to define a environment variable in codebuild and pass it to an Ec2 machine somehow or at least to refer to it in the appspec in codedeploy?

I tried to address it by echoing the variables into a file on my EC2 machine in the appspec, but I could output only the environment variables, that I defined in the appspec file itself.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? If you're trying to use an AWS service on the EC2 instance, this should typically be solved via IAM roles. If you're trying to use a secret for something else, Parameter Store or Secrets Manager might be good choices.